# LSI MegaRAID Bios - Loop where I have to delete Virtual Drive because of Preserved Cache

Tags: bios, lsi, megaraid

My server crashed tonight. I suspect the disks being full. I have four SSDs of the same kind connected to a LSI MegaRaid 4-port controller. The disk in slot 1 seems to be troublesome. I guess I could get it replaced.

[image: Logical view]

The problem I am running into now when I choose *Manage Preserved Cache* - the cache being the problem in the first place - my only option is to delete the *Virtual Drive*.

[image: Discard Preserved Cache]

Deleting the *Virtual Drive* really is not an option. This would delete all my data, right? I am having trouble finding understandable documentation on this.

[image: Delete offline drive]

(How) Can I *import the Virtual Drive* as stated in the below message?

[image: Message on Preserved Cache]

Is there any chance from this point to see why the disk in Slot 2 failed?

Any hints/help is very much appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you lost access to *two* disks, the ones in Slot1 and Slot2. If true, this means that your RAID5 array is inoperable - and the controller is asking you to delete it

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of that but I thought the current problem was a step before that.